# MySQL LIKE more results than expected

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Why does this LIKE-statement

```
WHERE configuration_key LIKE 'MODULE_SHIPPING_DP_%'
```

shows results like this:

```
MODULE_SHIPPING_DPD_STATUS
MODULE_SHIPPING_DP_STATUS
MODULE_SHIPPING_DPD_TAX_CLASS
MODULE_SHIPPING_DP_TAX_CLASS
```

I only wanted to get results with

```
MODULE_SHIPPING_DP_foobar
```

I dind't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because underscore `_` is like the `%` except you only look for one character [(cf documentation)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

You need to escape the character by using `\` before like this :

```
WHERE configuration_key LIKE 'MODULE\_SHIPPING\_DP\_%'
```

Comment: How could I solve it for determination of MODULE_SHIPPING_DPD_ and MODULE_SHIPPING_DP_ ?

Answer (score 1):

_ is also a wildcard, matching one character.  So you need to escape it.

```
WHERE configuration_key LIKE 'MODULE\_SHIPPING\_DP\_%'
```